# Stability of an equilibrium solution with 0 denominator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm testing the equilibria of a differential equation and found that one has a 0 denominator. Example:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=2x^{(1/2)}-5$$

Which, when you try and evaluate the derivative at 0, you end up with

$$f'(0)= \frac1{x^{1/2}}$$

being undefined. So how do I handle its stability there?

Comment: $0$ is not an equilibrium, so the issue doesn't arise in this case.  But you might try looking at $dx/dt = 2 x^{1/2}$ (or maybe better $dx/dt = 2 |x|^{1/2}$), for which interesting things happen.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I see your point haha, dumb example. I was just trying to make one up to illustrate the issue. I figured out my question from context but, in general, is there a systematic way to figure these 0 denominator things out?

Comment: @azmoti is there a systematic analytic method for this type of issue though? or should I just search graphical options.

Comment: If $f(p) = 0$ and for some $\epsilon > 0$ either $f(x) > 0$ for $p < x < p+\epsilon$ or $f(x) < 0$ for $p-\epsilon < x < p$, then $p$ is an unstable equilibrium.  If for some $\epsilon > 0$ we have $f(x) <  0$ for $p < x < p+\epsilon$ and $f(x) > 0$ for $p-\epsilon < x < p$, then it is asymptotically stable.